# CodeCharge Studio alternatives for Mac?

Tags: macos

I'm a happy user of [CodeCharge Studio](http://www.yessoftware.com/products/product_detail.php?product_id=1) but sadly it's the only reason to have a virtual machine with parallels, everybody here use a Mac. Does anyone know some other tool that generates PHP code and runs under OS X?

Answer (score 1):

None that would be as good Code Charge Studio.

I run vmware fusion on my macs just for Code Charge Studio, and it's worth it to me until YesSoftware creates a mac version, hint hint.  I'd love to have it run nativity on my mac!!!

Answer (score 0):

According to it's website, [ScriptCase](http://www.scriptcase.net/scriptcase-features/) is usable through a web-browser.

The APEEL PHP Generator site has done some [comparisons](http://www.phpcodegeneratorpro.com/reviews.php) of other PHP Code Generators:

The reviews are pretty fair and cover costs, installation and some comments about generated code structure. Most of them, however, are Windows only.

Having said that, I also use CodeCharge Studio in VMWare on my Mac and am very happy with it in comparison to other tools. I work in both .NET and PHP projects and so the single tool for both (and switching between languages) is fantastic.